# wait until driver switch to default content selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, iframe, selenium-webdriver

I am running test on multiple websites but for some reason one of them is running extremely slow. I have an iframe and basically what is happening is that it is not switching to default content fast enough, is there any reliable way of checking if driver switched to default content?

**CODE**

```
//Get tweet box element
        Wait.Until(
            ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath(
                "//a[contains(@class, 'tweet-box')]")));

        //Leave iframe 
        Program.Driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
```

*I need some sort of check if Driver is on Default content now, if so, proceed.*

Comment: Think of it in a different way, don't think "I need to wait for it to switch" but rather, I need to be wait until "X" (which happens to be in the default frame) is visible. That's the solution, wait for your next command to succeed.

Comment: @Arran Thank you very much for your advise it does make sense certainly, but I was already aware of it. I was just wondering if there is any more specific of waiting for driver to switch from iframe to default content or vice versa.